# Unable to identify a webelement using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have to click on a close button in an application. So, I tried to identify the element using xpath but I ended up with the element is not visible exception. So, I just used `Thread.sleep(5000)` and it did throw `No Such Element exception` and then

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//img[@src='https://healthhomestg.gsihealth.com:6161/dashboard/dashboardapp/sc/skins/EnterpriseBlue/images/headerIcons/close.png']")));
```

but still I ended up with `No such element exception`. Then id in the div tag and name in the img tag get changed dynamically for every page load. Please help me in identifying the close button and click on it

xpath that I used:

```
"//img[@src='https://healthhomestg.gsihealth.com:6161/dashboard/dashboardapp/sc/skins/EnterpriseBlue/images/headerIcons/close.png']"
```

Code snippet for the close button is given below

```
<div id="isc_9L" class="imgButton" role="button" onscroll="return isc_ManageCareTeamWindow_0_closeButton.$lh()" style="position: absolute; left: 1057px; top: 2px; width: 15px; height: 15px; z-index: 202052; overflow: hidden; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;" eventproxy="isc_ManageCareTeamWindow_0_closeButton">

<img width="15" height="15" border="0" align="TEXTTOP" draggable="true" suppress="TRUE" name="isc_9Lmain" src="https://healthhomestg.gsihealth.com:6161/dashboard/dashboardapp/sc/skins/EnterpriseBlue/images/headerIcons/close.png">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src*='close.png']"));
```

So, here we are identifying the element IMG by cssSelector, which has src attribute inside that could contain "close.png".

Comment: Thanks, Stanjer. I tried the code you have given but no click operation took place. Point to highlight is that the application under test has been developed using GWT and I guess user-extensions.js and user-extensions-ide.js has to be configured with IDE or Selenium RC but I am supposed to configure them in webdriver (selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 //img[contains(@src,'headerIcons/close.png')]
```

Comment: Thanks, Aditya. I tried it in the xpath and no click operation was performed and ended up with the following error though I used Thread.sleep(), implicit and WebDriverWait. The application has been developed using GWT and I guess user-extensions.js and user-extensions-ide.js has to be configured with IDE or Selenium RC but I dont know how to do it with webdriver
 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with